# Set html checkbox and input tag from javascript using a variabe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a json string of form

```
{
      "user_id"            : "4BtIrO4vgJUZG3wUxDjihnKbYvw2"
    , "travel_mode"        : "plane"
    , "travel_with"        : [ "family", "couple" ]
    , "travel_preferences" : "national"
    , "budget"             : "321"
}
```

Now I want to set `travel_mode` check-box to plane through js
Html for this is

```
<input class="traveltype" onclick=" " type="radio" name="options" value="car" id="radio1"></input>
<input class="traveltype" onclick=" " type="radio" name="options" value="plane" id="radio2"></input>
<input class="traveltype" onclick=" " type="radio" name="options" value="train" id="radio3"></input>
<input class="traveltype" onclick=" " type="radio" name="options" value="walk" id="radio4"> </input>
```

How can I do this

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to include your html

Comment: Very less information, no code is provided.

Comment: I have edited the question, please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var data = {
  "user_id": "4BtIrO4vgJUZG3wUxDjihnKbYvw2",
  "travel_mode": "plane",
  "travel_with": ["family", "couple"],
  "travel_preferences": "national",
  "budget": "321"
}

$("input[type=radio][value=" + data["travel_mode"] + "]").prop("checked",true)
```

**demo**

```js
var data = {
  "user_id": "4BtIrO4vgJUZG3wUxDjihnKbYvw2",
  "travel_mode": "plane",
  "travel_with": ["family", "couple"],
  "travel_preferences": "national",
  "budget": "321"
}

$("input[type=radio][value=" + data["travel_mode"] + "]").prop("checked",true)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="traveltype" onclick=" " type="radio" name="options" value="car" id="radio1"></input>
<input class="traveltype" onclick=" " type="radio" name="options" value="plane" id="radio2"></input>
<input class="traveltype" onclick=" " type="radio" name="options" value="train" id="radio3"></input>
<input class="traveltype" onclick=" " type="radio" name="options" value="walk" id="radio4"> </input>
```